# After ajax google analytics tag not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-analytics, gtag.js

I am using google analytics to measure every event on my web page. When gtag scripts embed directly html working well (i always confirm event google anlytics ) but after ajax codes not working and no action in google analytics center. What does that i miss?
Here is my ajax codes for add to cart event

```
function addtocart(){

 $.post(url,{}, function (response) {


    
        $("#shopping-cart").html(response.Render);
        $(".sepette_modal").css("display", "flex"); 
        setTimeout(() => {
            $(".sepette_modal").css("display", "none");  
            $('#' + Urun_kodu).html(`

        <i class="icon_cart_alt"></i>Add to cart
    `);
        }, 1500);




        //below gtag() function not working
        gtag('event', 'add_to_cart', {
            "transaction_id": response.Urun_kodu,
            "affiliation": "Marketcimrisi",
            "value":response.Fiyat,
            "currency": "TRY",
            "tax": 0,
            "shipping": 0,
            "items": [

                {
                "id": response.Urun_kodu,
                "name":  response.Urun_adi,
                "list_name": response.Detaykategori,
                "brand": response.Marka,
                "category": response.Detaykategori,
                "variant": "",
                "list_position": 1,
                "quantity": 1,
                "price": response.Fiyat
                },
                
            ]
   
    },'json');

});
```

Comment: Sounds like a JS issue, not PHP. Please only add tags that are directly relevant to the question at hand.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't send transaction information with add to cart event. To measure the addition of a product to a shopping cart, send an add_to_cart event with the product information:

```
gtag('event', 'add_to_cart', {
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "P12345",
      "name": "Android Warhol T-Shirt",
      "list_name": "Search Results",
      "brand": "Google",
      "category": "Apparel/T-Shirts",
      "variant": "Black",
      "list_position": 1,
      "quantity": 2,
      "price": '2.0'
    }
  ]
});
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/enhanced-ecommerce#measure_additions_to_and_removals_from_shopping_carts

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have found the solution after an ajax request must recall google analytics tags

```
   $.getScript("https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-171652858-1",function(){});

   window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
   function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
   gtag('js', new Date());

   gtag('event', 'purchase', {
        "transaction_id": response.SiparisNumarasi,
        "affiliation": "Marketcimrisi",
        "value":response.OdenenTutar,
        "currency": "TRY",
        "tax": 0,
        "shipping": 0,
        "items": JSON.stringify(response.Urunler)
   });
```